# Hyperlink has a batch file behind it. Clicking it returns 404

Tags: hyperlink, iis-6

The title says it all, there is a batch file behind a link:

click me

Clicking on it returns a 404 error.
I also tried navigating to this batch file right from Chrome / IE.
It still returns a 404.  The file exists, permissions are good, event viewer has no errors.

Its running in IIS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry looks like I found it by just adding a mime type of application/bat with extension bat.
I found this in the IIS settings of the actual site.